# Using UTF8 INSTR in SQLite

Tags: unicode, utf-8, sqlite

I'm trying to use `INSTR` function in SQLite but it returns wrong value If I use UTF8 character. How can I avoid this problem?

```
select instr('akçe', 'a'); --returns 1 (Correct)
select instr('akçe', 'k'); --returns 2 (Correct)
select instr('akçe', 'ç'); --returns 0 (Wrong)
select instr('akçe', 'e'); --returns 3 (Wrong)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
> select instr('akçe', 'ç');
3
> select instr('akçe', 'e');
4
```

Apparently, you are not actually using UTF-8.

Check that the output of `select quote(cast('ç' as blob));` is `X'C3A7'`.

Comment: select quote(cast('ç' as blob)); --returns X'87' for me.

Comment: That's some DOS codepage. I guess you're using `sqlite3.exe` in the Windows console.

Comment: yes, you are right. now, I understand the problem, I will try it outside of the console. thanks...